# Two Rails applications, one userbase, looking for a simplest solution to handle this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-plugins, beast

I have two Rails applications, let's call them A and B. A has existing user base and i want these users to be able to log in to B with the username and password managed in A.

B is altered version of Altered Beast forum and it would be nice if users of my application do not have to create another user account to use forum. My initial thought was just to swap out the User model with ActiveResource model. Forum is hosted on a different server so direct database connection to A's database is too much trouble.

My question is that is there any plugins or authentication system extensions that handle this kind of setup.

Answer (score 2):

Altered Beast uses the `restful_authentication` plugin. Could you not just use the same plugin in application A pointed to the same database?

Edit:

Use a [cooooooookies](http://nessence.net/2009/10/26/restful-authentication-subdomain-fu-needing-cookie-adjustments/) from application A.

Comment: Sorry, i left out that the beast site is hosted on another server and doing some sort of tunneling to A's database is not worth the trouble. Edited my post.

Comment: Ah. Well then. What about using cookies? Does this help? http://nessence.net/2009/10/26/restful-authentication-subdomain-fu-needing-cookie-adjustments/